# Exception when calling

Tags: java, hashcode

I would like to ask a question for computing a hashvalue for a empty file. I need to compute a hash_value when the file f is first created and is empty. Then, at the end I will update the hash_value again. My code is not working for windows os. Can you tell me how to handle this? Thanks.

```
            objectFile = File(fullFilePath);
            fileInputStream = FileInputStream(objectFile);
            data = IOUtils.toString(fileInputStream, 'UTF-8');

            persistent digest;            

            if isempty(digest)
                digest = MessageDigest.getInstance('SHA-256');
            end

            hash = digest.digest(java.lang.String(data).getBytes('UTF-8'));
```

Error Message

```
    digest.digest(java.lang.String(data).getBytes('UTF-8'))
    Java exception occurred:
    java.lang.NullPointerException

        at java.security.MessageDigest.update(Unknown Source)

        at java.security.MessageDigest.digest(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even come close to compiling, for a start.

Comment: Your code looks like some script instead of java code.

Comment: yes, a matlab script

Comment: either digest or data is null. As "NullPointerException" reference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like `data` is null, so instead of the following statement:

```
hash = digest.digest(java.lang.String(data).getBytes('UTF-8'));
```

Can you write this:

```
if isEmpty(data)
    hash = 0;
else
    hash = digest.digest(java.lang.String(data).getBytes('UTF-8'));
end
```

Comment: @downvoter reason for downvote?